# How to disable/Enable the button from the viewModel of different WPF c# Project

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am new to WPF. I have two WPF C# projects, project1 as the reference of the project2. Now there is a button in the view model of project2, Based on a function which is present in project2, I want to disable the button present in viewmodel of the project1.
What I tried:

Project2 ViewModelA:

```
button Enability
 public bool _isStartEnabled = true;
        public bool isStartEnabled
        {
            get { return _isStartEnabled; }
            set
            {
                _isStartEnabled = value; RaisePropertyChanged("isStartEnabled");
         }
       }
```

Then after that:
project1 ViewModelB:

Made object of ViewModelA after adding dependency of project2 in project1

```
ViewModelA VM_A;


public void funcA(){
 VM_A._isStartEnabled = false;
}
```

But _isStartEnabled method is not hitting in ViewModelA when I put the breakpoint.

Where I am going wrong,I will be good if someone can help out in it.

Answer (score 1):

```
VM_A._isStartEnabled = false;
```

Sets the public field _isStartEnabled, it does not run through the property code. This is a good example of why you should **never** have public fields in C#.

```
VM_A.isStartEnabled = false;
```

Will work (also following standard C# naming, it should be called "IsStartEnabled")